# How do I get "storageBucket" in Firebase to generate?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage

Firebase keeps giving me empty "" instead of generating a URL for "storageBucket" when I try to get the code to paste into my HTML for login through Google. I am assuming this is the reason I am getting the error: This domain is not authorized for OAuth operations for your Firebase project. Edit the list of authorized domains from the Firebase console.(anonymous function) @ iframe.js:84

I am using browser sync to user localhost which is supposed to be an authorized domain. I have the firebase cdn in my header of my HTML and everything that was generated for my firebase app (except for the storageBucket). I tried importing my app to the new Firebase, just typing in my app name in a similar storage bucket URL ("eventSpot.appspot.com") and I tried just creating a new app in Firebase. None of these worked. Is there something I am missing?

Thanks in advance for your help! :)

Comment: What happens when you visit the storage tab?  Are you able to upload files there?

Comment: It says "Can't connect to server. Try again in a few minutes"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The storage tab can take some time just after project creation - but if you've left it a little while and you're still getting the error, it may be some APIs have not been enabled.

Can you go to https://console.developers.google.com/project/_/apis/enabled

Check for:

- App Engine Admin API
- Google Cloud Storage
- Google Cloud Storage JSON API

If any aren't enabled, enable them. After that, try the storage console again.

Comment: Thanks, Ian. All of those APIs were already enabled. I'm not sure how long I would have to wait after project creation, but it has been about five to six hours. I am still getting the "Can't connect to server. Try again in a few minutes."

Is there something else that I could be missing?

Comment: Can you check if you have any buckets created for you project in Cloud Storage: https://console.developers.google.com/storage/browser?project=_ - there should be on there by default. If it is there, please try refreshing the Firebase Console storage tab a few times, see if that resolves it?

Comment: Thanks, Ian. This worked on the second app I made. The first one I imported from the old Firebase and still isn't working, but that is fine. I will just use the new one. I really appreciate your help! :)

Comment: If you imported your project and having the problem, see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38526042/1757321