# Firebase Storage Can't Connect, Retry again

Tags: firebase-storage

I imported an old project into Firebase when I joined.

On the https://console.firebase.google.com/project/project-name/overview page, when I try to grab the code snippet to initialize my Firebase, the storage bucket shows up with empty URL.

Today, I started a new project, this time, using the Firebase console. After creating the project, the StorageBucket URL showed up in the initialization code snippet automatically.

When I check both project's storage rules, I see the URL pointing to the right places, however, the imported project gives this error under the Storage > Files tab:

[image]

It has been like this since day one I imported the project.

When I went to https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser to see if the new project I created would show, it did.

Are there any extra steps on my part to get the storage bucket URL to show for the imported project?

Comment: There are some known issues importing existing projects into Firebase Storage. Can you please send a support request to firebase.google.com/support with the project ID and a link to this post, so we can troubleshoot?

Comment: @MikeMcDonald Hi. Thanks for the heads up. Just sent a support request using this form: https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/ I hope that was the right channel to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Who's this answer for?**

If you imported your project into Firebase and having the above issue specifically with your Firebase Storage.

After back and forth with Firebase Support, if you're facing similar problems as mine, here's the approach you can try. I'm trying to replay the conversation and steps given by the Firebase Support

- Make sure that you are the owner of the project you are accessing.
- If you have multiple Google accounts signed in, Firebase Database can't
  seem to connect to the server. Sign into incognito mode
- Check in your API Manager if the following are enabled
- a) App Engine admin API
- b) Firebase Rules API
- c) Google Cloud Storage
- Check if you have an App Engine app is enabled    https://console.developers.google.com/project/_/appengine
- Go to Firebase Storage AppManager tab
  https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/
- a) Add the service account firebase-storage@system.gserviceaccount.com as an owner on the storage bucket: .appspot.com.
- b) Additionally, you need to edit the "object default permissions" to allow for similar access.

Now, if you have all the above in place, next step is this:

**Add new Server Credentials**

In [credentials page](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials), ( https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials ),

- click Create credentials, select API key
- Select server key
- Put name as "Server key (auto created by Google Service)"

At the time of writing this, creating the Server Key was what got it to work.

**A few words:**

The issue of not able to use Firebase properly when two accounts are logged in the same browser doesn't plague me anymore. Logged into two accounts, and both Firebase projects are up and running without any issue.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed mine by using the command to work on it using

```
firebase init storage
```

This would create the storage after that it would add a storage.rule in which you can update to your liking in your project .
Then you run this command

```
firebase deploy --only storage
```

This would initialize the Storage

If you are still having issues check out this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/74750337 which was also provided by firebase for me to fix the error
This is how i fixed mine

Answer (score 0):

It's about daily quota.Daily quota is 1GB and if you exceed the quota.Storage will not load.I asked that to Firebase support and they told me

> you need to wait until midnight US Pacific Time for the daily quota to
> reset

for bandwith quota.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).